# How do I show an image/icon on NSTabViewItem using swift macOS App in Xcode 13.2.1

Tags: swift, macos, image, icons, nstabview

step1. I new a project in Xcode 13.2.1 with macOS App, swift and storyboard

step2. The default NSViewController named ViewController

step3. I added a NSTabView on ViewController and I connected first NSTabViewItem to ViewController and select Outlet and named tab. I set tab.label and tab.image shown below.

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var tab: NSTabViewItem!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tab.label = "Tab"
        tab.image = NSImage(named: "icon.png")
    }
}
```

step4. I run the App and the image(icon.png) didn't show.

I would like to show an image/icon on NSTabViewItem like picture below.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7Scv.png)

How do I show an image/icon on NSTabViewItem? Could you provide a sample code? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: From NSTabViewItem.h: "The image may only be used in certain tab view styles and options.". Post a [mre] please.

Comment: @Willeke I have posted a example. What kind of certain tab view styles and options can support image?

Comment: I think the image is used by `NSTabViewController`.

Comment: Did you figure out any work arounds? It seems the image attribute is just ignored by NSTabViewItem